# How can I access data from my Microsoft SQL Server 2000 on the client side?

Tags: sql-server, database, connection

Right now I have Microsoft SQL Server ready configured, I want to use it for accessing database to more than one computer in a LAN. How should I go with it?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean here but there are several options for accessing data in a database.

You can write a program in a language such as C# which uses ADO.NET to access the database. You can also use excel to get data from the database. SQL Server will support having more than one client so having multiple computers accessing it will not cause any problems.

If you give us a bit more infomration about what you are trying to do we might be able to help you out a little more.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the SQL Server 2000 client tools from the same installation medium. That will give client computers access to the **SQL Server Enterprise Manager** and **Query Analyzer**.

Connect to your database using your server's name and your credentials (Security/Login).

Answer (score 0):

Open corresponding port on the server firewall if any.
For basic tasks you can setup an ODBC dsn the get the datas.

Answer (score 0):

Set up an ODBC connection on the client computers then use an application (e.g access or a custom written app) to connect to the database.